# How come I have a working copy with a subdirectory without .svn in it?

Tags: svn

I have a svn working copy checked out. The root directory has a .svn subdirectory. However, the other subdirectories of the project don't have a .svn hidden directory in them. They do contain versioned files. I thought every subdirectory has to include its .svn. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using subversion version 1.7.x which has this working copy enhancement (**WC-NG**). In this feature, only root working copy contains hidden directory to hold pristine copies (original versions). See [here](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/10/11/top-new-features-in-subversion-1-7-wc-ng-pristines/) to understand rationale behind WC-NG feature.

Answer (score 3):

This is the feature of Subversion 1.7. From the [Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#single-db):

> A key feature of the changes introduced in Subversion 1.7 is the
>   centralization of working copy metadata storage into a single
>   location. Instead of a .svn directory in every directory in the
>   working copy, Subversion 1.7 working copies have just one .svn
>   directory—in the root of the working copy. This directory includes
>   (among other things) an SQLite-backed database which contains all of
>   the metadata Subversion needs for that working copy.